# filter result using 2 JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my saved localstorage,

```
[{"industry_Id":1,"merchant_id":2}]
```

I want to filter below result, to get HP.

```
{
    "industries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "oil and gas",
            "merchant": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "ABC",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "DEF",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "GHJ",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "IT",
            "merchant": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Apple",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "HP",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Google",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought of using multiple $.each but it have to iterate few times and it's quite redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using Javascript `for` loop, that way you can skip iterating over every object once required element is found.

**Without jQuery** (using `for`)

```
var i, j, merchant = null;
for(i = 0; i < data['industries'].length; i++){
   if(data['industries'][i]['id'] == arg[0]['industry_Id']){
      for(j = 0; j < data['industries'][i]['merchant'].length; j++){
         if(data['industries'][i]['merchant'][j]['id'] == arg[0]['merchant_id']){
             merchant = data['industries'][i]['merchant'][j];
             break;
         }
      }

      if(merchant !== null){ break; }
   }
}
```

**With jQuery** (using `$.each`)

```
    var merchant_found = null;
    $.each(data['industries'], function(i, industry){
       if(industry['id'] == arg[0]['industry_Id']){
          $.each(industry['merchant'], function(i, merchant){
             if(merchant['id'] == arg[0]['merchant_id']){
                merchant_found = merchant;
             }

             return (!merchant_found);            
          });
       }

       return (!merchant_found);
    });
```

```js
var arg = [{"industry_Id":1,"merchant_id":2}];

    var data = {
        "industries": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "oil and gas",
                "merchant": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ABC",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "DEF",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "GHJ",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "IT",
                "merchant": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Apple",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "HP",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Google",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };


    var i, j, merchant = null;
    for(i = 0; i < data['industries'].length; i++){
       if(data['industries'][i]['id'] == arg[0]['industry_Id']){
          for(j = 0; j < data['industries'][i]['merchant'].length; j++){
             if(data['industries'][i]['merchant'][j]['id'] == arg[0]['merchant_id']){
                 merchant = data['industries'][i]['merchant'][j];
                 break;
             }
          }
          
          if(merchant !== null){ break; }
       }
    }
    
    console.log(merchant);
    document.writeln("<b>Without jQuery:</b><br>");
    document.writeln((merchant !== null) ? "Found " + merchant['name'] : "Not found");

    var merchant_found = null;
    $.each(data['industries'], function(i, industry){
       if(industry['id'] == arg[0]['industry_Id']){
          $.each(industry['merchant'], function(i, merchant){
             if(merchant['id'] == arg[0]['merchant_id']){
                merchant_found = merchant;
             }
            
             return (!merchant_found);            
          });
       }

       return (!merchant_found);
    });
    
    console.log(merchant_found);
    document.writeln("<br><br><b>With jQuery:</b><br>");
    document.writeln((merchant_found) ? "Found " + merchant_found['name'] : "Not found");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I prefer using $.each but return false doesn't stop it from looping, do u have idea why?

Comment: @AaronMusktin, added solution using `$.each`, returning `false` breaks loop at current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectors.map(function(selector) {
  return data.industries.filter(function(industry) {
    return industry.id == selector.industry_Id;
  })[0].merchant.filter(function(merchant) {
    return merchant.id == selector.merchant_id;
  })[0].name;
});
// => DEF
```

If you want "HP", you want industry 2, not industry 1.

`.filter(...)[0]` is not really optimal. You could use `.find(...)`, but that is not yet universally supported. Or you could use plain old JavaScript and write for loops instead to make it fast. Or you could use objects with ID keys instead of arrays to make lookups faster.

Comment: map() is the cleanest method but doesn't it faster than $.each?

Comment: Well, you didn't say what should happen if `selectors` had more elements. That said, `map` should have more or less the same speed as `each` (with just creation of an array as additional overhead, which should be imperceptible). The bigger potential problem is `filter` continuing to search for additional matches, even when we already know we only want the first match.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes into a position where collection of data is what you're processing, I suggest you to take a look at **underscore.js**. It's not optimal choice for the best performance but *it does make you code more readable and makes more sense especially when compared with loop*.

Say `data` is a variable which stores your JSON data. 
Try this:

```
// Given this selector criteria
var select = [{"industry_Id":1,"merchant_id":2}];

function filterByCriteria(criteria, data){
    var match = [];
    _.each(criteria, function(crit){

        function matchIndustry(rec){ return rec.id===crit.industry_Id }
        function matchMerchant(rec){ return rec.id===crit.merchant_id }

        // Filter by industry id
        var industry = _.first(_.where(data.industry, matchIndustry));
        // Filter by merchant id
        var merchant = _.where(industry.merchant, matchMerchant);
        _.each(merchant, function addToMatchResult(m){
            match.push(m.name);
        });
    });
    return match;
}

var filteredData = filterByCriteria(select, data);
```

From snippet above, any merchants which match the search criteria will be taken to the match list. Is it more readable to you?

Answer (score -1):

Do you even need numerical id's? Gets super easy when you don't.

```js
/*
{
    "industry": {
 "oil and gas":{
            "merchant": {
         "ABC": {
                    "name": "ABC oil"
         },
                "DEF": {
                    "name": "DEF gas"
                },
                "GHJ" :{
                    "name": "GHJ oil and gas"
                }
            }
 },
 "IT": {
            "merchant": {
         "Apple" : {
                    "name": "Apple computers"
                },
                "HP": {
                    "name": "Hewlett Packard"
                },
                "Google": {
                    "name": "Google. Maw haw haw"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
*/
var data = '{"industry": {"oil and gas":{"merchant": {"ABC": {"name": "ABC oil"},"DEF": {"name": "DEF gas"},"GHJ" :{"name": "GHJ oil and gas"}}},"IT": {"merchant": {"Apple" : {"name": "Apple computers"},"HP": {"name": "Hewlett Packard"},"Google": {"name": "Google. Maw haw haw"}}}}}';
data = JSON.parse(data);

var merchant = data.industry['IT'].merchant['HP'];

alert(merchant.name);
//console.log(merchant.name);
```

Comment: Hi Aaron. I'm new to stackoverflow. Nice to meet you too.

Comment: In the face of a downvote, & since you mentioned redundancy.   I fail to see how the industry & merchant are not acceptable id's, therefore fail to see why you have the extra redundancy built into your db schema. Must you hide the name from the user? If you have the ability to reformat the db (which was essentially my question) then my example means you never need to filter (more redundancy), because as long as you know what you are searching for, you can access it directly.Your localstorage would simply be [{"industry_Id":"IT","merchant_id":"HP"}]

Comment: I didn't actually think it was you who had downvoted me. I suspect you would have done that earlier if it was your intention.